# How to hide div and make it clickable to show an overlay for media screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a `read-more` div with a font-awesome icon in a yellow background. This only shows when screen size is smaller than 767px. When this div shows then a user can click it to see the `.overlay`. 
If screen size is bigger than 768px then the `read-more` should not show and when a user hovers-over the image then the overlay shows (this currently works).
What I cannot solve:

1. How to hide the `read-more` div completely for screens > 768px?
2. How to make the `read-more` div clickable and when clicked the
   `.overlay` shows?

```js
$(function() {
  var overlay = $('.overlay');
  $("#product-detailscar").one('click', function(e) {
    overlay.appendTo(document.body)
  });
});
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .read-more i {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .product-detailscar:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.product-detailscar .overlay {
  /*.well.carousel .overlay {*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  border-top: 1px solid #A10000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A10000;
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  /*padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="read-more"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide `.read-more`:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
     #read-more {
         display:none;
     }
}
```

To make `.overlay` clickable:

```
$("#read-more").click(function() {
    $(".overlay").show();
});
```

To hide `.overlay` on click:

```
$(".overlay").click(function() {
    $(".overlay").hide();
});
```

Comment: Simple, elegant, and robust. Great answer.